# System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll: Where does it come from?

Tags: .net-assembly, dll

Which framework/SDK/update or whatever stuff installs this dll?

We've been trying to identify the source of the dll, with Silverlight 4,  RIA Services, Silverlight 5 SDK thought of as suspects but apparently none of them are guilty.

Comment: At least describe where you found the dll.  Sounds more like a namespace (Internal, not Internals), like used in Microsoft.Transactions.Bridge.dll

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. This is actually a dll that is located as part of .NET Framework 4 (under C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319). Feels like a part of some kind of in-place update

Comment: Sorted it out. It's a part of .NET 4.5, appeared with dev11 preview installation.